# Status of Highly Qualified Professional visa after quitting the job

Tags: working-visas, spain

I moved to Madrid/Spain (from a non-EU country) with a job that provided the Highly Qualified Professional (Profesionales Altamente Cualificados) visa type recently. Initially, the visa has a one-year duration.

*After a month in the company, it is getting evident that their expectations and mine are far from each other. It seems like at some point, either I am going to get fired because of under-performing or I will quit because of pressure/burn-out.*

Regarding this visa type, I have two questions,

1. If I quit at some point, can I stay in Madrid until the end of the visa duration or does my visa get voided with the job contract?
2. If I try to switch jobs, does the new company need to do the visa-application process all-over or the visa I already have right now is transferrable/directly useable(I don't know what is the word for this but hopefully this is understandable)?

Comment: Did you get an answer for this? I'm in a similar situation, don't want to quit but its always good to know the possibilities.